# add field on result of Dql

Tags: symfony, left-join, arraycollection, doctrine-query

I'm trying to associate a field of my entity with a left join :

```
$query = $em
->createQueryBuilder()
->select('Page, partial Template.{id,name}')
->from('WHCmsBundle:Page', 'Page')
->leftJoin('WHCmsBundle:Template', 'Template', 'WITH', 'Page.Template = Template.id')
->orderBy('Page.root, Page.lft', 'ASC')
->getQuery()
;
$result = $query->getResult();
$tab = new Collections\ArrayCollection($result);
```

I have got that :

```
0 => Page {#1002 ▶}
1 => Template
2 => Page {#1116 ▶}
3 => Template
```

But i want that :

```
0 => Page {#1002 ▼
  -id: 25
  -name: "Home"
  -Template: => {
   ....
  }
  -slugReplace: null
  - ...
```